# iphone image suddenly change to hover image

Tags: iphone, css, jquery-mobile

I'm developing an iPhone application using PhoneGap. In order to identify when the button is clicked, we have changed the active image of the button.

```
<a class="grid-image btn-image-pharmacycard" onclick="location.href='#prescriptionCard';">
```

Here is the css:

```
.btn-image-pharmacycard
{
 background: url("../image/iphone/pharmacy-card-iphone.png") no-repeat scroll left top transparent; 
}

/* while focus Pharmacy card in gird image, change another image*/
.btn-image-pharmacycard:hover, .btn-image-pharmacycard:focus
{
    background-position: left bottom;
}
```

Sometimes what happens is that, in the application, without clicking the button, the hover image is shown instead of the normal one.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Possibly not relevant but is there any need for the hover on this since it's a phone app?

Comment: since i developing phonegap application to say that I have clicked a button i have added hover image

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"></meta>
```

iPhone trying to be user friendly and always hover to some html inputs.

setting the scale to 1 will always disable any zooming or hovers